# Bullet entering target

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

I've been given this question:

> A bullet entering a target with an initial velocity of $ u $ loses $\frac {u}{n}$ of its velocity after penetrating a distance $ a $ into the target;  how much further will it penetrate?

My question is, doesn't some information about the nature of the bullet's acceleration need to given? How otherwise would I formulate the kinematic equations?

Comment: Given the answer, we can explain what assumptions your book wants to make.

Comment: You should get $x=\frac{a}{n^{2}-1}$ for the remaining distance that the bullet travels.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I know that assuming constant acceleration,  the problem is easily solved. I just wanted confirmation that thjs is insoluble without making any other assumptions

Comment: A distance $a$?  I want to punch this book's author.

Answer (score 0):

You should assume uniform retarding Force is provided by surface. Use conservation of energy.

$Fa=\Delta KE$ and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct that some assumptions need to be made. Different $a(t)$ or $a(x)$ profiles could meet the given information and yet give different final solutions.